# How to change the value of dataGrid Cell automatically c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two columns in dataGrid view :

```
Price
Amount
```

and a third column

```
total
```

how can I make when the value of `Price` and `Amount` changes the value of `total` field change automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way in Win app grid :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == 0 || e.ColumnIndex == 1)
         this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = System.Convert.ToInt32(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) * System.Convert.ToInt32(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: The value of Total cell should be the result of Amount cell value multiplied by the Price cell value